# Access a named parameter with string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty newbie in ruby and I'm not sure that the question be suitable, but this is my problem.

I have a function with unlimited string parameters. I want to know if all of them are in the http request. This is my code :

```
def http__params_exists *list
    list.each do |p|
        if params[:'#{p}'].nil?
            return false
        end
    end
    true
end
```

Take an example : I have a query with the "lat" parameter. The condition that I want to be execute is `if params[:lat].nil?`

I tried some tricks, but all failed.
Thanks.

ps :An other question about ruby. I don't know exactly the kind of objects that symbols like `:method_not_allowed` (for example) are. I know that we can call a function naming some parameters, but this object is already defined somewhere, as if it was a public variable of the controller, but it doesn't seems to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"` instead of `'` so that the variable is interpreted. Example

```
a = 'string'

:'#{a}'
==> :"\#{a}"

:"#{a}"
==> :string

:"#{a}" == :string
==> true
```

So, your code shall be

```
...
if params[:"#{p}"].nil?
  return false
end
...
```

[This](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol) is an interesting link to learn more about Ruby symbols.

Comment: `p.to_sym` would be another option.